# Why does a new responsive website rank lower in Google than competitors that are not optimized for mobile?

Tags: seo, ranking, google-ranking

I have a project which is fully responsive and has been optimized for mobile devices using caching, gzip, optimal images and so on.

The website is released 3 - 4 weeks ago and scores pretty well. Around position 1 till 10 for some of our pages.

But sometimes I see that we are on position 4 or 5 or 6 but the competitors above on 1 and 2 and 3 are having a non responsive website. Even the speed is not optimized. When I check the backlinks and Moz DA and PA, then these are not that different.

What can be the cause for this? Does it need some more time in order to rank better then our competitors or... ?

For the last week the positions are quite stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many factors that contribute to your ranking, that we can't possibly tell what exactly is wrong.

I can tell you that in *this* case it isnt speed or responsiveness that makes the difference (because, well, you just said so). However, those are two important factors. This means that something more significant is happening, which *might* be one of the following:

- Your competitor has an older website, giving it more authority
- Your competitor has other flows/backlinks which are worth more
- You have made an update, give it a few weeks to balance out
- Your responsive version has mistakes, maybe htmlerrors, which don't help
- Their content might simply be better, more up-to-date, better written

Keep checking your WebmasterTools and Google Analytics, see where you can improve. And again, give it some time.

Comment: thanks for the intel. Yes the competitors sites are older. We have no errors in html, completely valitated. Yes we have added a few changes so we will wait that out.

Comment: [Mobile friendly site won't give you benefits in desktop/tablet search](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/04/faqs-april-21st-mobile-friendly.html).

Comment: More importantly, his competitors probably have relevant content.

Answer (score 2):

Responsive is one factor that influences ranking. As you say domain authority is around the same perhaps the competitor pages outranking yours are better keyword optimised.

Try and look at ways you can optimise keywords on the page from both a content and technical perspective. I.e primary keywords in H1 tags, URLs and Title Tags. Check your H-tag hierarchy as a whole, make sure you're using primary, secondary and LSI keywords that are relevant.

We usually allow around 6 months for SEO changes to take affect. Your site is only 3-4 weeks old as you say. Give it time.